# the database of a website that i connect to from a vb.net application is not updated

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows application in VB.NET, and a IIS web site. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition.

My windows application works with data from the database of the website. I've connect to database, but when new data is inserted in the database through the website, in my windows app the database does not contain that new data.

I need the database to be updated. How can I do that?
Is it possible?

Comment: which database you are using; how do you read data in your windows application

Comment: ms sql database. I use an SqlDataReader to read data from database. I've declare the connection like this: Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Service1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True") ...is it ok? ..could be "DataDirectory" the problem?

Comment: your database connection pointing to a local file, basically you have to connect to the same database that is used in your web site; if web site is local then change windows app connection to the web site database

Comment: my web site is local. how can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point your windows application database connection to the web site database.
For example if your web site is located in C:\inetpub\yourwebsite\App_Data, then you can do either:

Set path in AttachDbFilename

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\yourwebsite\App_Data\Service1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

Or use Relative Path

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.setData(“DataDirectory”,”C:\inetpub\yourwebsite\App_Data\”);
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Service1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```